# Getting Recently selected ListViewItem in c#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am wokring in windows application on which I have a multi selected ListView. I am handling selection_changed event to get recently selected item. I select the first item and after that I select second and third item. But in selectedItem Property of listview I still get the first element where element 2nd and 3rd should come respectively. 
How can I achieve this?
This is my code.

```
 private void CategoryListview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {        
            OfferCategory selectedCategory = (OfferCategory)CategoryListView.SelectedItem;
      }
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent to SelecteItems you could use?  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx

Comment: Stuart Dunkeld is correct - in MultiSelect mode, you need to use the SelectedItems property of the ListView, which returns a ListViewItemsCollection. Not sure what your OfferCategory class is, but if it is a singular object, you will need to modify your code to handle a list-type return value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that was something like

```
ListView.SelectedIndices
```

So SelectedIndices is a collection holding all selected cells :) ListView.SelectedIndices[0] gives you the row currently selected. But attention! You have to check for ListView.SelectedIndices[0] > 0 !!

Comment: Yes, but how can I get to know about recently selected item, if 2 items are already selected. and I am selecting the third one.

Comment: You could use a combination of SelectionChanged and SelectedIndices to track changes within your listview selection into a private variable.

Comment: HOw can i change the background of listview item dynamically?